# Prefer Dependency-Injection over Partial Mocking?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ocmock, partial-mocks

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139752/when-to-use-partial-mocks) SO question, but it deals with the subject in more general terms.

Should I prefer using partial Mocks over Dependency Injection? My question is based on the following quote from OCMock:

```
id aMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:anObject]
```

> Creates a mock object that can be used
>   in the same way as anObject. When a
>   method that is not stubbed is invoked
>   it will be forwarded anObject. When a
>   stubbed method is invoked using a
>   reference to anObject, rather than the
>   mock, it will still be handled by the
>   mock.

This means I could stub my (property-)dependecies away using a partial mock instead of injecting them in the constructor (or via setter injection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should design your API so that it makes sense as a general-purpose API, not particularly to support unit testing or dynamic mocks.

The pattern you suggest is simply a variation of the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern, except that the method is a property. If you think that, in general, it makes sense to implement your dependency access as virtual properties, then you can use the technique you describe. This is a well-known unit testing technique called *extract and override*.

However, I would be vary of doing this for a number of other reasons.

- Even if you can override the dependency, the default may drag in references to the 'real', intended depdendency creating a tighter coupling than you may want.
- If you forget to *extract and override*, the default dependency is used, and you may not want that. Sometimes it's better to be explicit about the intended usage.

Comment: +1 - Choose mocking or DI based on what works best for your code.  Not the other way around.